# How to simulate acceleration and then deceleration?

Tags: vector

Currently I am only using deceleration.

Here is how I do it

I need to cover Vector(x,y) unit distance to reach B from A.

I simply do -

rendering loop->

1. position = A + Vector(x,y).scale(factor);
2. Vector(x,y) = Vector(x,y) - Vector(x,y).scale(factor);

...factor = 10 for example
So if I have to cover 100 units, I cover 10 then 9 then 8.1 and so on in every frame.

How do I simulate acceleration then deceleration here?

Comment: Acceleration changes velocity in the same way velocity changes position. So, change your velocity over time to simulate acceleration. (BTW, "deceleration" isn't really a separate thing, it's just a short way of saying "acceleration in the direction opposite of travel")

Comment: Your have basically simulated drag coefficients, although you'd genereLly have a different "factor" for drag vs whatever your doing with position there, which some people struggle quite a bit with, so good job there.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to animate the object using a [smoothstep curve](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t3pytxdukl):

```
lerpFactor = (curTime - startTime) / timeToReachTarget;
smoothstepFactor = lerpFactor * lerpFactor * (3.0 - 2.0 * lerpFactor);
position = lerp(startPos, targetPos, smoothstepFactor);
```

Here, I'm assuming a specified amount of time to reach the target (`timeToReachTarget`) and calculating how far the object should have moved by the current time (`lerpFactor`), then passing it through the smoothstep curve to make it accelerate and decelerate smoothly.

This isn't an especially physics-based approach, nor does it work well if the target point is moving, but it does create a smooth-looking motion.

Comment: `lerpFactor * lerpFactor * (3.0 - 2.0 * lerpFactor)` is not the same that `3x^2 -2x^3`, is there an error ?

Comment: @kosokund They're the same; I just wrote it in a factored form that avoids redundant calculations.  It's a common trick for polynomials.